# While loop not not correctly looping else conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
board = ["-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]

i = False
user_input=input("Enter position: ")

while not i:

    while user_input not in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
        user_input=input("Enter position: ")

    block = int(user_input)-1

    if board[block]=="-":
        i = True
    else:
        print("Position not available, try again")
```

I have written a `while` loop which should loop until `i` is `True`, when the `if` conditional doesn't meet the condition it should move to `else`, print the statement, then loop through again. But it's printing the `else` statement endlessly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. What exactly do you enter? Do you really use Python 3? Or Python 2 accidentally?

Comment: Put a print statement after you compute block. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because if the user intput is not in your list, your variable called user_input remains the same and thus you can't reach the inner while lopp anymore.

you can try the following :

````
board = ["-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]

user_input=None # Set it to None by default

while "Input not correct": #a string is always evaluated as true, thus you can give a more explicit condition


    user_input=input("Enter position: ") #prompts user for an input
    try:
        block = int(user_input)-1
    except ValueError:  #if the user enter something else than a position
        print("Position must be an integer")
    try:
        if board[block]=="-": # will raise an IndexError if block is not a valid index
            break #if the condition is satisfied it will quit the while lopp
    except IndexError:
        pass
    print("Position not available, try again") # if we're here it means that the input was not correct (either there is no '-' in the block or the block doesn't exists)
       ```
Hope this will help you
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the code to keep asking for a number as long as the program is `true` and its in that list of numbers. Does this do what you are asking for?

```
board = ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]

i = False
user_input = input("Enter position: ")

while not i and user_input in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
    taken_number = []
    user_input = input("Enter position: ")
    block = int(user_input)-1
    taken_number.append(block)
    if board[block] == "-":
        i = False
    else:
        break

print("Position not available, try again")
```